# php -v command changes cmd font

Tags: php, cmd, fonts

When I type `php -v` in a cmd windows font will change as you can see in the images below:

Before using PHP:

[image: Before using PHP]

After using PHP:

[image: After using PHP]

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you clarify: did the font change after you typed `php -v`? what did you mean by "After using PHP"?

Comment: Courier New, 12